# How do you write a relative path in elasticsearch.yml?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to provide a value for path.data that is relative to the installation location of ElasticSearch.

Is it possible to do something like this?

`path.data: {ES_DIR}/../../data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
path.data: ${path.home}/../../data
```